# Strength parameter in collation not woking in in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to use mongoose in order to send a query to get data but it has to be case insensitive. I'm doing this:

```
model.find({ name: /etoile/i }).sort({ popularity: -1 })
    .collation({ locale: 'fr', strength: 1 })
```

I want to get data that contains `etoile` and `étoile` but it doesn't seems to work...

Comment: This is not supported at the movement. However if you create an text index on `name` field will do the  job

Comment: @Ashh in my model should i set for the `name` field `index: true` and then I will be able to use strength ?

Comment: No... create an index using command... `schema.index({ name: "text" })`

Comment: something like `modelSchema.index({ name: 1 });` ?

Comment: The functionality you are trying to get is called "accent insensitive".

Answer (score 0):

this does not work `modelSchema.index({ name: 1 })`,

you can try this code out, I just tried it and it worked

`User.findOne({email:req.body.email}).collation( { locale: "en",  strength: 2 })`

or going by your code just use this

`model.find({ name: /etoile/i }).collation({ locale: 'fr', strength: 1 })`
then sort it after the selection from the model